# Learning Java (and Programming) on Udemy. Need help to understand logic

Tags: java, recursion

I am currently watching a video on recursion, and I need some help with the logic in it.

I don't understand the return "moment" of the algorithm.
Here is the code:

```
public class App {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // E.g. 4! = 4*3*2*1 (factorial 4)

        System.out.println(factorial(5));
    }

    private static int factorial(int value) {
        //System.out.println(value);

        if(value == 1) {
            return 1;
        }

        return factorial(value - 1) * value;
    }

}
```

What I don't understand is the `return 1;` part.
When the method is calculating the factorial of 4, it recalls it self until value becomes 1.

But when `value == 1`, the method is supposed to **return 1 to the caller of the method**.
Doesn't this `return 1` overrides  `return factorial(value - 1) * value;`??

Clearly, I don't completely understand how `return` works.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: if the value is `1` it returns `1`. The caller of the recursiv funcition will now return `1 * value`, whose caller will return the result of the previous `2 * value` and so on. Just look at your comment and read it from the right to the left with each part beeing a return. `1` is a return, `2*1` is a return, `3*2` is a return, `4*6` is the last return of the recursiv method.

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger or println statement and see what happens.

Comment: You could start with asking yourself what would happen if the `return 1;` statement wasn't there. Hint: the name of the website you are on.

Comment: I wouldn't call it override. The moment code hits a `return` it exits the current method and continues at the place where the method was called, with the return value in that place. No need for `break` after `return` because that line of code cannot be reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of every recursion is "stop point", the condition, when recursion does not continue, but instead returns value. If this point does not exist, the recursion nevers ends.

This is how it will be called :

```
System.out.println(factorial(5))
-return factorial(4)*5
--return factorial(3)*4
---return factorial(2)*3
----return factorial(1)*2
-----return 1
----return 1*2
---return 2*3
--return 6*4
-return 24*5
System.out.println(120)
```

---

I think it is more clear, when you put "return" outside the recursive counting, because you are doing more stuff in one line.

I made this program, ignore "doMinuses" method, it only makes minuses to make output more readable. It does the same thing as your program. You do not have to read it, just look to output first.

```
public class App {
    public static int origValue = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(factorial(origValue));
    }

    private static int factorial(int value) {
        doMinuses(origValue-value);
        System.out.println("Entered factorial("+value+")");
        if(value == 1) {
        doMinuses(origValue-value);
        System.out.println("Returning 1");
            return 1;
        }

        doMinuses(origValue-value);
        System.out.println("Start countin factorial("+(value-1)+")*"+value);
        int factorialResult = factorial(value - 1) * value;
        doMinuses(origValue-value);
        System.out.println("Returning result for factorial("+(value-1)+")*"+value + " = " + factorialResult);
        return factorialResult;
    }

    private static void doMinuses(int count){
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.print('-');
        }        
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Entered factorial(5)
Start countin factorial(4)*5
-Entered factorial(4)
-Start countin factorial(3)*4
--Entered factorial(3)
--Start countin factorial(2)*3
---Entered factorial(2)
---Start countin factorial(1)*2
----Entered factorial(1)
----Returning 1
---Returning result for factorial(1)*2 = 2
--Returning result for factorial(2)*3 = 6
-Returning result for factorial(3)*4 = 24
Returning result for factorial(4)*5 = 120
120
```

---

The only difference outside printing out code is to change this line

```
return factorial(value - 1) * value;
```

to two lines, because it is, what is really happening (especially the order of what is happening).

```
        int factorialResult = factorial(value - 1) * value;
        return factorialResult;
```

---

I edited function even more for BEST output ever :)

```
public class App {

    public static int origValue = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(factorial(origValue));
    }

    private static int factorial(int value) {
        doMinuses(origValue - value);
        System.out.println("Entered factorial(" + value + ")");
        if (value == 1) {
            doMinuses(origValue - value);
            System.out.println("Returning 1");
            return 1;
        }

        doMinuses(origValue - value);
        System.out.println("Start countin factorial(" + (value - 1) + ")*" + value);
        int factorialResult = factorial(value - 1);
        doMinuses(origValue - value);
        System.out.println("Finished counting factorial(" + (value - 1) + ") = " + factorialResult);
        doMinuses(origValue - value);
        System.out.println("Returning result for factorial(" + (value - 1) + ")*" + value + " = " + factorialResult + "*" + value + " = " + (factorialResult * value));
        return factorialResult * value;
    }

    private static void doMinuses(int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.print('-');
        }
    }
}
```

Has this output :

```
Entered factorial(5)
Start countin factorial(4)*5
-Entered factorial(4)
-Start countin factorial(3)*4
--Entered factorial(3)
--Start countin factorial(2)*3
---Entered factorial(2)
---Start countin factorial(1)*2
----Entered factorial(1)
----Returning 1
---Finished counting factorial(1) = 1
---Returning result for factorial(1)*2 = 1*2 = 2
--Finished counting factorial(2) = 2
--Returning result for factorial(2)*3 = 2*3 = 6
-Finished counting factorial(3) = 6
-Returning result for factorial(3)*4 = 6*4 = 24
Finished counting factorial(4) = 24
Returning result for factorial(4)*5 = 24*5 = 120
120
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me the most. I understand recursion, somehow, I just didn't understand why return 1; doesn't override the return, and why break; isn't placed instead of return;

Comment: I analyzed it more, it turns out, I didn't understand recursion :) Thanks for the heads up again :)

Comment: @Kokolo did you know anything about the stack? understanding how the memory works will dramatically help you to understand a recursive function.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot @libik, this helps a lot. 

I've read Head First Java which has a clear explanation on how stack works, but originally I had no Idea the thing I didn't understand (`return 1;`) had to do with stacking. @Eekan

It's all clear now.
Thanks again @libik for taking time to explain this nicely.
Also, as a noob, I learned as well how to debug with sysout thanks to you. :)

Answer (score 2):

`Return 1` does override the `return factorial(value - 1) * value;`

But what this function is doing is calling itself, up until the value hits 1.

Once the value hits one, the if condition is met and the `return 1` part is called, completely ending the function (kind of like a `break;` would, to put it simply), so it will stop executing the `return factorial(value - 1) * value;`

Comment: Aha, so it's like 'feeding' the stack until it returns 1, and than executing all those stuff on the stack. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Returned value '1' comes from this expression

```
return factorial(value - 1) * value;
```

and is used only here, previous lines will never be evaluated.

In this case, recursion works similarly to a loop. To understand how it works, you may use debugger, or try to write down each instruction (statement, expression) in order in which it will be evaluated.

for factorial(3)
it will look like this

```
factorial(3)
if(3==1) //false
factorial(2) //to return factorial(2) * 3 when function becomes evaluated
if(2==1) //false
factorial(1) // //to return factorial(1) * 2 when function becomes evaluated
if(1==1) //true
return 1;
return /*factorial(1) = */ 1 * 2;
return /*factorial(2) = */ 2 * 3; //return 6 - result of your top call of factorial(3) from the main call
```